# How to remove an element in an array of strings

Tags: java, string

im fairly new at coding. I have an array of movies. What im trying to do is delete the movie with the least number of sales. In my method 'remover' located in the box office class, i get an error saying " int cannot be dereferenced" on the line including this code "((movies.get(i).sales).equals(small))". also i called the remove method to delete it from the array but im guessing that remove isnt legitimate in java. What call would i have to make to remove it from the array and update the length.

```
import java.util.*;
public class LIANGLAB1p2
{
    public static void main(String[] argv)
    {
        BoxOffice bo = new BoxOffice();
        bo.add(new Movie("starboat","pg","action"));
        bo.add(new Movie("bloody banquet","pg-13","horror"));
        bo.add(new Movie("godizilla eats tokyo","pg","horror"));
        bo.add(new Movie("geeks in love","pg","comedy"));
        bo.add(new Movie("bad cop, worse cop","r","comedy"));
        bo.add(new Movie("lost of bullets","r","action"));
        bo.add(new Movie("the eliminator","r","action"));
        bo.add(new Movie("the garbage collector","pg","comedy"));
        bo.add(new Movie("the dentist","r","comedy"));
        bo.add(new Movie("the professor","r","horror"));
        bo.add(new Movie("bloody noon", "r", "action"));

        for(int i=0;i<200;i++) bo.sellticket("the professor");
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++) bo.sellticket("starboat");
        for(int i=0;i<120;i++) bo.sellticket("the eliminator");
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++) bo.sellticket("bloody banquet");
        for(int i=0;i<40;i++) bo.sellticket("the dentist");
        for(int i=0;i<25;i++) bo.sellticket("geeks in love");
        bo.listmovie();
        bo.genrecounter();
        System.out.println("The most popular genre is " +bo.genrecounter());
        System.out.println("The most popular movie is " +bo.mostpopular());



        System.out.println("The sales have been reset to 0");
        bo.reset();


    }
}
class Movie
{
    public int sales;
    public int genr;
    public String title;
    public String rating;
    public String genre;

    public Movie (String t, String r, String g){
        title = t; rating = r; genre = g; sales = 0; genr = 0;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return title+ " - rated " +rating+" - genre: "+genre;
    }
}

class BoxOffice{

    List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<>();

    public double ticketprice;
    public void changeprice(double newprice){       
        ticketprice = newprice;
    }//changeprice

    public BoxOffice(){                 // constructor
        ticketprice = 10.00;
    }//BoxOffice

    public void add(Movie m){           //adds movie
        movies.add(m);
    }//add

    public void listmovie(){            //prints list of all movies
        for (int i=0; i<movies.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(movies.get(i).toString());
        }
    }//listmovie

    public int get(String t){           //gets movie by title
        for (int i=0; i<movies.size(); i++)
            if (t.equals(movies.get(i).title)){
                return i;
            }
            return -1;
    }//get

    public void sellticket(String m){   
        int i = get(m);
        if (i>=0)
            movies.get(i).sales +=1;
        else
            System.out.println("that movie is currently not showing");
    }//sellticket

    public String mostpopular() {   //returns name of most popular movies
        String ax = "";
        int bx = -1;
        for (int i=0;i<movies.size();i++)
            if (movies.get(i).sales>bx)
            {
                ax = movies.get(i).title;
                bx = movies.get(i).sales;
            }
        return ax;
    }//mostpopuler

    public void reset(){
        for (int i=0;i<movies.size();i++){
            movies.get(i).sales = 0;
        }
    }

    public void remover(){
        int small = movies.get(0).sales;
        for (int i=0;i<movies.size();i++){
            if (movies.get(i).sales < small)
                small = movies.get(i).sales;
            }
        for (int i=0;i<movies.size();i++){
            if ((movies.get(i).sales).equals(small))
                remove(movies.get(i));
        }
    }

    public String genrecounter(){   //returns most populer genre
        int horror = 0;
        int action = 0;
        int comedy = 0;
        for (int i=0;i<movies.size();i++)
            if ((movies.get(i).genre).equals("horror")){
                horror++;
            }
            else if((movies.get(i).genre).equals("comedy")){
                comedy++;
            }
            else {
                action++;
            }
        if (horror > action || horror > comedy){
            return "horror";
        }
        else if (action > comedy || action > horror){
            return "action";
        }
        else {
            return "comedy";
        }
    }


}//BoxOffice
```

Comment: Although you keep saying `array`, `movies` is a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

Comment: its = new ArrayList<> though, so its not an array?

Comment: While an `ArrayList` does use an array as its backing store, you're not operating on it directly.  For that matter, because `movies` is declared as `List<Movies>` as its type, it could be created as a `LinkedList<Movies>` or `CopyOnWriteArrayList<Movies>` and the other code would remain the same.  This is because you're programming against the `List` interface and not an `ArrayList` specifically.

Answer (score 2):

if `movies.get(i).sales` returns an int, you can't call `.equals` (or any instance method) on it, since `int` is a primitive type. Use `movies.get(i).sales == small` instead.

As for removing an item from the ArrayList, you can do it with `movies.remove(i)`, but note that as a side effect, this would change the index of all the elements in the list with index > i, so if you continue iterating over the list after the removal, you should process the i'th element again.

Therefore, you should change the loop inside `remover` to :

```
    for (int i=0;i<movies.size();i++){
        if (movies.get(i).sales==small) {
            movies.remove(i);
            i--;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A java `List` does have a remove method, where you can specify the index or object to remove. So your code can be simplified to:

```
public void remover() {
    Movie smallest = movies.get(0);
    for (Movie movie:movies) {
        if (movie.sales < smallest.sales) {
            smallest = movie;
        }
    }
    movies.remove(smallest);
}
```

A simple explanation:
1) Get the first movie, initially set it as the movie with lowest number of sales
2) Loop all movies, checking each if sales are lower than the lowest so far
3) If they are lower, then update the reference to the movie with the smallest number of sales
4) Finally, remove the movie with the lowest number of sales from the list, via object reference

Comment: can you explain how this code works, what does int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE; do,

Comment: I have changed it since then, but the `int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE` just sets your `min` variable to a large number, to allow `sales` to be smaller. If `min` was `0` then nothing would be smaller (unless you had negative sales)